# error in R plot_usmap() when trying to color counties by outcome variable

Tags: r, aesthetics

I'm trying to map an outcome measured at the county-level in Idaho.  I'm not understanding the error message below.  The following code reproduces the error.  I've tried limiting map.data to just one row per county, but this also results in an error.

```
require(usmap)
require(ggplot2)

map.data <- usmap::us_map("counties",
                          include = "ID")
dim(map.data)
1090   10
```

random outcome values for plotting by county

```
n.county <- length(unique(map.data$fips))
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame( fips = unique(map.data$fips),
                 values = runif(n.county))
head(d)
    fips    values
 1 16001 0.8966972
 2 16003 0.2655087
 3 16005 0.3721239
 4 16007 0.5728534
 5 16009 0.9082078
 6 16011 0.2016819
```

merge to add "values" variable to map.data

```
map.data <- merge( map.data, d)
map.data <- map.data[ , c("fips", "values")]
dim(map.data)
1090   2

plot_usmap( regions = "counties",
            include = "ID", 
            data = map.data,
            values = "values") + 
  labs( title = "Idaho",
        subtitle = "Outcome Y")
```

**R error:**

This is the R error I get:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
>   Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (35884): fill

Next, I planned to color the counties based on the "values" using the following:

```
  + scale_fill_continuous( low = "white", 
                           high = "red", 
                           name = "Legend", 
                           label = scales::comma) + 
  theme( legend.position = "right")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem comes from the name of the second column of your dataframe, that you called "values". Maybe `plot_usmap` breaks when the argument `values` calls a column called `values`.

Your code works when the name of that column is "X" for example:

```
require(usmap)
require(ggplot2)

map.data <- usmap::us_map("counties", include = "ID")
dim(map.data)
n.county <- length(unique(map.data$fips))
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame( fips = unique(map.data$fips),
                 X = runif(n.county))
head(d)

map.data <- merge( map.data, d)
map.data <- map.data[ , c("fips", "X")]
dim(map.data)
1090   2

plot_usmap( regions = "counties",
            include = "ID", 
            data = map.data,
            values = "X") + 
  labs( title = "Idaho",
        subtitle = "Outcome Y")
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a bug in `plot_usmap`.